# How to compare list elements for empty element?

Tags: python

The first input array is the key to the correct answers to an exam, like ["a", "a", "b", "d"]. The second one contains a student's submitted answers.

The two lists are not empty and are of the same length. Return the score for this list of answers, giving +4 for each correct answer, -1 for each incorrect answer, and +0 for each blank answer, represented as an empty string (in C the space character is used). If the score < 0, return 0.

For example:

```
checkExam(["a", "a", "b", "b"], ["a", "c", "b", "d"]) → 6
checkExam(["a", "a", "c", "b"], ["a", "a", "b",  ""]) → 7
```

My solution:
it is working fine for all other conditions:

```
def checkExam(arr1,arr2):
    total = 0
    for i,j in zip(arr1, arr2):
        if i == j:
            total += 4
        if i != j:
            total -= 1
        if total < 0:
            return 0
    return total
```

**
Execept this one:

```
checkExam(["a", "a", "c", "b"], ["a", "a", "b",  ""]) → 7
```

> The problem is that I don't know how to compare (**"b"**) with (**" "**) (empty element) so it return +0 for blank answer.

**

Comment: So if out of 100 answers, I get all of them correct except the first one, my score is 0? That doesn't seem fair. (`check_exam(['a'] * 100, ['b'] + ['a'] * 99)` returns `0`)

Comment: you  can simply check for `j== ''` to check for an empty string

Comment: BTW - calling your arguments arr1 and arr2 is not good - try to choose better variable names, it is a good habit to get into to use meaningfull names.

I would suggest that `arr1` should be renamed as `correct_answers`, and `arr2` be renamed as `given_answers`.
and that `i` and `j` should be `correct` and `given` respectively

Finally I think that your final `if` that checks for a negative socre should be outside of your loop - currently it exits the function as soon as the total goes negative - which could happen when the first answer is wrong.

Comment: Yes Thankyou will probably do it. It was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you return from inside the loop when you reach a negative total? Just apply the logic as given:

```
def check_exam(arr1, arr2):
    total = 0
    for i, j in zip(arr1, arr2):
        if i == j:
            total += 4
        elif j:  # only deduct if j is non-emtpy
            total -= 1  
    return max(total, 0)  # no negative marks

>>> check_exam(["a", "a", "b", "b"], ["a", "c", "b", "d"])
6
>>> check_exam(["a", "a", "c", "b"], ["a", "a", "b",  ""])
7
```

And if you really want a cryptic one-liner:

```
def check_exam(arr1, arr2):
    return max(0, sum(4*(i==j) or -bool(j) for i, j in zip(arr1, arr2)))
    # or less cryptic
    return max(0, sum(4 if i==j else -1 for i, j in zip(arr1, arr2) if j))
```

Comment: your code will end up giving negative marks which i tthink he doesnt want

Comment: Thank you I understand now.

Comment: How about a non-cryptic oneliner? The straight-forward one is only two characters longer.

Answer (score 2):

try this i think it solves your issue..let me know if it doesn't. even i new to this so any help with code improvement will be great

```
def check_exam(arr1,arr2):
    total = 0
    for i,j in zip(arr1, arr2):
        if i == j:
            total += 4
        elif j=="": #i have made a change here
            total += 0
        elif i != j:
            total -= 1
    return max(total,0)
```

Comment: Thanks bro it is easy to understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it as you would in real life. You know, on paper. Where you wouldn't compare a not-given answer to the expected answer at all. Where you'd skip that entirely.

```
def check_exam(expect, given):
    total = 0
    for e, g in zip(expect, given):
        if g:
            total += 4 if e == g else -1
    return max(0, total)
```

One-liner version:

```
def check_exam(expect, given):
    return max(0, sum(4 if e == g else -1 for e, g in zip(expect, given)))
```

Other one-liners:

```
def check_exam(expect, given):
    return max(0, sum((-1, 4)[e == g] for e, g in zip(expect, given)))
```

```
def check_exam(expect, given):
    return max(0, sum(f'    {e}'.find(g) for e, g in zip(expect, given)))
```

The latter one would also handle `' '` correctly (well, like `''`):

```
>>> check_exam(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'b', '', ' '])
3
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want

```
def check_exam(solution, student_submit): 
  scores = [0 if y == "" else 4 if (y==x) else -1 for (x,y) in zip(solution,student_submit)]
  return max(sum(scores),0)
```

Comment: return statement is now added

Comment: Also it returns negative scores, which should be normalised to zero

Comment: Thanks @TonySuffolk66 missed that part in the Question, added this now

Comment: your version does calculate the sum twice - which isn't great....